# Solana - How to get the balance from my Phantom wallet?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, smartcontracts, solana, phantom-wallet

I'm working on a web app that can connect to Phantom Wallet. I've established the connection and have successfully retrieved the wallet's public key. The problem is, I can't seem to find any solution to get the account balance.

For reference, I wanted to display the account balance just like how solanart.io displays it.

Note that I've gone through all related docs (Solana/web3.js, Solana JSON RPC API etc). Please guide me as I'm still new to JSON RPC API.

For a heads up, I'm using vanilla js.

```js
try {
      const resp = window.solana.request({
        method: "getAccountTokenBalance",
        params: [
          id, //wallet's public key
          {
            encoding: "base58",
          },
        ],
      });
      console.log(resp);
    } catch(err) {
      // error message
    }
```

Comment: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getBalance this should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RPC method that you're using does not exist.  You'll want to use `getBalance` to get the SOL on the wallet: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getbalance

To get all of the non-SOL token balances owned by that wallet, you'll have to use `getTokenAccountsByOwner` using that wallet id: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokenaccountsbyowner

Comment: Thanks Jon for pointing this out. I've changed my code structure and used the getBalance. Finally, it works!

Comment: What did you change your construct to? Can you please provide a working Vanilla example? I have a connection, and I can get the address, but when I run this line to get a balance I get a -32603 error. var balance = window.solana.request({
          "jsonrpc": "2.0",
          "id": 1,
          "method": "getBalance",
          "params": [wallet_address]
   });

Comment: I'm getting the wallet_address from: var wallet_address = window.solana.publicKey.toString();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69609838/how-to-get-solana-account-info-and-or-sol-balance-using-vanilla-js-and-json-rpc

Comment: How can you get metadata on nft

Answer (score 2):

```
import { useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react'
import { LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js'
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor'


const wallet = useWallet()
const SOLANA_HOST = clusterApiUrl("devnet")
const connection = new anchor.web3.Connection(SOLANA_HOST)

let lamportBalance
if (wallet?.publicKey) {
        const balance = await connection.getBalance(wallet.publicKey)
        lamportBalance=(balance / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL)
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me to get SOL Balance

```
  const [userSOLBalance, setSOLBalance] = useState<number>()
 if (wallet.publicKey) {
  const SOL = connection.getAccountInfo(wallet.publicKey)
  SOL.then((res) => setSOLBalance(res.lamports / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL))
}
```